# Unexpected token j in JSON but there is no token j

Tags: jquery, html, json, jsonp

I have this code with lots of text and I need to make a JSON for it.So far I was doing Ok but now I get a strange error. This is the code.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h2 class="heading">
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <p class="text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
          ea commodo consequat.
          <a href="javascript:;" class="inline-link">Duis autem veleum</a> iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent
          luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-8">
        <ul class="content-list">
          <li>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit
          </li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci.
          </li>
          <li>Lbh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h3 class="sub-heading">
          I am page subheading
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <p class="text">
          At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia
          animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda
          est, omnis dolor repellendus.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <p class="text last-txt">
          Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur
          aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

```js
var content = '{"rowCol":{"col":[{"heading":"I am page heading"},`{"text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <a href="javascript:;" class="inline-link">"Duis autem veleum</a> iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi."}]}}';

$(document).ready(function() {
  var obj = JSON.parse(hero);
  divData(obj);

  function divData(obj) {
    for (i in obj.row.col) {
      $('.col-10 .title').text(obj.row.col[i]);
    }
    for (i in obj.rows.col) {
      $('.col-12 .title').text(obj.rows.col[0].title);
    }
    for (i in obj.rows.col) {
      $('.col-12 .btn').text(obj.rows.col[1].button);
    }
  }

  //This one
  var cont = JSON.parse(content);
  divData(cont);

  function divData(cont) {
    for (i in cont.rowCol) {
      $('.col-12 .heading').text(cont.rowCol.col[i].heading);
    }
  }
```

The last one is the problem. I am getting a console error like this : 
Uncaught

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token j in JSON at position 341
>           at JSON.parse ()
>           at HTMLDocument. (main.js:22)

It is showing me this position in code: `var cont = JSON.parse(content);` 
I don't see any j token here ... or anywhere else .

Comment: The hero is working correctly . I need the solution for the second part. For the "cont"

Comment: The problem is because of the `"` within the JSON string. You need to escape them, ie. `\"` Also note that you have a random ` character in the example above, which I assume is just a typo

Comment: Yeah that is a typo. so where i have " i have to put \" ... Ok wil ltry that

Comment: Then note that your `for..in` loop is invalid for the array you have. Just use a `forEach()` or standard `for` loop.

Comment: I have never used forEach() . Can you give me an example please ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Thank you. I shall check it out